# Scrolling up in putty shows no history. Only by resizing the window can i see output history. How can I fix this?

Tags: putty

Attempting to scroll back through the output history of putty only shows the initial login prompt directly above the oldest output currently on the putty screen. However, when I resize the window it self it will show more of the output history.

How can I fix this so I'm able to scroll back through the history like normal?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/518222/how-can-i-scroll-up-to-see-the-past-output-in-putty

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not related to Unix&Linux. Putty is a windows terminal emulator. Maybe ask on superuser.com (they probably already have an answer there).

Comment: Putty is open source, and has a linux client version too. 
@F5-- may you specify which OS are you using?